# Target all Select fields not just first using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that changes the text of an option within a select field. I have multiple select fields on a page with variable IDs so I cannot target each one individually. At the moment i seem to only be targeting the first select field on the page however I need this to loop for each select field that is on the page. What have I missed?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Change first option text on dropdowns
$("select").val($("select option:first").text('Please select an answer...').val());

// Set first option as selected
$("select option:first-child").attr("selected", true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="wpProQuiz_field_83" id="forms_10_13" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="83">

  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice">Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice">Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning">Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning</option>
  <option value="Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice">Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice</option>

</select>



<select name="wpProQuiz_field_84" id="forms_10_16" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="84">
  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very confident">Very confident</option>
  <option value="Somewhat confident">Somewhat confident</option>
  <option value="Unsure">Unsure</option>
  <option value="Not very confident">Not very confident</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please explain, you need only for first select box , or for every select box the first option should be text to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:nth-child() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead of [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector as it selects first matched element.

> Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

```
$("select option:nth-child(1)").text('Please select an answer...').prop("selected", true);
```

**Note:**

> Because jQuery's implementation of `:nth- selectors` is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of `n` is "1-indexed

OR, [`:first-child Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$("select option:first-child").text('Please select an answer...').prop("selected", true);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select :nth-child(1)").text('Please select an answer...').prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="wpProQuiz_field_83" id="forms_10_13" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="83">

  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice">Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice">Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning">Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning</option>
  <option value="Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice">Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice</option>

</select>



<select name="wpProQuiz_field_84" id="forms_10_16" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="84">
  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very confident">Very confident</option>
  <option value="Somewhat confident">Somewhat confident</option>
  <option value="Unsure">Unsure</option>
  <option value="Not very confident">Not very confident</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Clear description made it easy to understand so makes sense why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Check any of these.

```
$("select option:first-child").text('Please select an answer...');
// or
$("select").find('option:first').text('Please select an answer...');
// or
$("select").find('option:eq(0)').text('Please select an answer...');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option:first-child").text('Please select an answer...');
  //$("select").find('option:first').text('Please select an answer...');
  //$("select").find('option:eq(0)').text('Please select an answer...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="wpProQuiz_field_83" id="forms_10_13" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="83">

  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice">Very effective: The learning will have a major impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice">Effective: The learning will have a minor impact on my practice</option>
  <option value="Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning">Partly effective: The learning confirmed that there was no need to modify my practice/I may modify my practice with further learning</option>
  <option value="Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice">Not effective: The learning was not relevant to my practice</option>

</select>



<select name="wpProQuiz_field_84" id="forms_10_16" data-required="1" data-type="7" data-form_id="84">
  <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
  <option value="Very confident">Very confident</option>
  <option value="Somewhat confident">Somewhat confident</option>
  <option value="Unsure">Unsure</option>
  <option value="Not very confident">Not very confident</option>
</select>
```